# Python regular expressions, use of OR

Tags: python, regex

I have a question about Python re's | operator:

The following regular expression where I use more than one character in an option of the | operator gives an expected result:

```
>>> ps = "^[23|45]"
>>> p = re.compile(ps)
>>> p.match("23")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001EE0370>
```

Also, I can add an end-of-string symbol when I use 1-character options in |:

```
>>> ps = "^[2|4]$"
>>> p = re.compile(ps)
>>> p.match("2\n")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001EE0440>
```

But when I try to use multiple-character option in | I do not get a match where I expected a match:

```
>>> ps = "^[23|45]$"
>>> p = re.compile(ps)
>>> p.match("23\n")
>>> ps = "^[2|4]$"
```

Also, I tried using the "\n" character instead of "$", the "search"-method instead of "match", but to no avail.
How can I make the last regular expression work?

Comment: use http://regex101.com/ and http://jdownloader.org/_media/knowledge/wiki/gui/settings0.7/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.png?w=650&h=883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  [23|45] `|` inside `[]` is useless and acts as palceholder for `|` instead of `or` operator.
Use `(?:23|45)` instead.
Also `[23]` will match `2`,`3`.Inside character class the sequnce doesnot matter.

The frst example works as the character class is `[23|45]` so `2 or 3` will match(only `2` matches here .if you use `^[23|45]$` you will not get a match).Third will not match as `\n` is not in the character class.

Comment: Fantastic, that's it! So how come that the first example works?

Comment: `[23]` will not match `23`. It will match `2` and `3`, separately, but it will not match `23` together. i.e. `re.match("[23]", "23").group(0) == "2"`

Comment: my guess the down-vote is because of this wrong statement `Also [23] will match 23,32,2,3.Inside character class`

Answer (score 1):

`^[23|45]$` will match a single character from the given list that is , it would match 2 or 3 or `|` or `4` or `5`. Anchors asserts that the line must have only one character. So this would match all the lines which has only one character i mentioned before.

And also `$` exists before the `\n` character. So this `re.match(r'^[2|3]$', '2\n')` returns you a match.

```
>>> ps = "^[23|45]"
>>> p = re.compile(ps)
>>> p.match("23")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001EE0370>
```

The above code will give you a match because `^` starting anchor, `[23|45]` any one character from the given list. Our input was `23` , so it matches the first `2`, finally it gives you a match and note that this won't match the whole text `23`. To match a string `23` or `45`, you must include the pattern inside a capturing or non-capturing group, not inside a character class.

```
r"^(23|45)$"
```